# Mock Identity column behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

I am mocking a `DbContext` for unit testing, and when you save changes in your database the instances you added pull the new id assigned by the database identity column, is there any way to mock this behavior?, I really have no clue where to start.

```
var acc = new Account {Name = "A New Account"};

_db.Accounts.Add(acc);
_db.SaveChanges();

Assert.IsTrue(acc.Id > 0);
```

Where

```
public class TestDbContext : IEntities
{
    public DbSet<Instance> Accounts { get; set; } = new MockDbSet<Accounts>();
}
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ControliApiTests.Data
{

public class MockDbSet<T> : DbSet<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<T> where T : class
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<T> _data;
    readonly IQueryable _queryable;

    public MockDbSet()
    {
        _data = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _queryable = _data.AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual T Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Derive from MockDbSet<T> and override Find");
    }

    public Task<T> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override T Add(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        var addRange = entities as T[] ?? entities.ToArray();
        foreach (var entity in addRange)
        {
            _data.Add(entity);
        }
        return addRange;
    }

    public override T Remove(T item)
    {
        _data.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override T Attach(T item)
    {
        _data.Add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public override T Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>();
    }

    public override ObservableCollection<T> Local
    {
        get { return _data; }
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _queryable.ElementType; }
    }

    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _queryable.Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return new AsyncQueryProviderWrapper<T>(_queryable.Provider); }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _data.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

internal class AsyncQueryProviderWrapper<T> : IDbAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    internal AsyncQueryProviderWrapper(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerableQuery<T>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new AsyncEnumerableQuery<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute(expression));
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Execute<TResult>(expression));
    }
}

public class AsyncEnumerableQuery<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>
{
    public AsyncEnumerableQuery(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) : base(enumerable)
    {
    }

    public AsyncEnumerableQuery(Expression expression) : base(expression)
    {
    }

    public IDbAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return new AsyncEnumeratorWrapper<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    {
        return GetAsyncEnumerator();
    }
}

public class AsyncEnumeratorWrapper<T> : IDbAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public AsyncEnumeratorWrapper(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<bool> MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get { return _inner.Current; }
    }

    object IDbAsyncEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define

```
private static int IdentityCounter = 1;
```

in your mock implementation and increment it by one for each added item, you will get an incrementing value that does not reset as long as the app domain exists.

If your tests allow for multi-threaded adds, use [Interlocked.Increment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) to update the counter.

Note that your current implementation does not demand that an object have an Id property. If all of the classes in the test have such a property, you can define an interface to use rather than allowing anything that is `class`.

```
public interface DbEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MockDbSet<T> : DbSet<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable<T> where T : DbEntity
```

With that change, your implementation of Add could look like

```
public override T Add(T item)
{
    item.Id = IdentityCounter++; // Or use Interlocked.Increment to support multithreading
    _data.Add(item);
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want use a interface can use reflection and extension method for take and evaluate the id

---

```
var MockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
MockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(MockData.AsQueryable().Provider);
MockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(MockData.AsQueryable().Expression);
MockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(MockData.AsQueryable().ElementType);
MockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => MockData.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());
MockSet.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(MockData.AddPlus); // here change te method 'Add' for the extension method 'AddPlus'
```

---

```
public static void AddPlus<T>(this List<T> miLista, T item) 
        {
            int nuevoId;
            int? id;
            try
            {
                id = (int)item.GetPropValue("id");
            }
            catch
            {
                id = null;
            }
            if (id == 0)
            {
                if (miLista.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var listaInts = miLista.Select(i => (int)i.GetPropValue("id"));
                    nuevoId = listaInts.Max(x=>x) + 1;
                }
                else
                    nuevoId = 1;
                item.SetPropValue("id",nuevoId);
            }
            miLista.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to include the extension methods, though